Aurora Borealis Mechanics; Solar Wind Glow Intensity In Unshielded Atmosphere
Question:
If you had a mass of unshielded atmosphere in space, somehow held together without expanding, how bright would the Aurora Borealis ionization effect be per unit volume? How much air would you need for it be visible to the human eye outside the Earth's magnetic field? In the Van Allen Belts?
Motivation:
I'm tinkering with some ideas for a magical science fiction setting. The premise is that magical fields of force which produce constant acceleration within their boundaries enable significantly easier spaceflight. One part of the premise is that this magic would provide an alternative method to pressure vessels for holding an atmosphere in vacuum - simply create a thick spherical shell of force directed inwards towards a platform to trap a volume of atmosphere.
Such a volume of air would be exposed directly to interplanetary radiation (there would also be significant heating and cooling concerns but that's a different issue). And so I'm curious if this would create any visibly perceptible light over relatively small volumes of air (think several swimming pools worth). I know the Aurora Borealis occurs over massive volumes of atmosphere, during exceptional solar flares, so I don't particularly expect the answer to be yes. But at the same time, the radiation in the Van Allen Belts is very intense so I'm not certain of the answer.
I've had some trouble finding resources which might let me calculate this for myself, so any help would be appreciated.

No, there would be no aurorae. Aurorae are produced by forbidden line radiation in the upper layers of the atmosphere, at pressures similar to the best terrestrial vacuums. The extremely low densities allow the very slow forbidden radiative transitions time to occur.
In higher pressure environments, the transitions are collisionally deexcited.

Well that answers the question very succinctly, thank you!
